# how to use textview in other class (MyThread extends Thread)

Tags: android, post, methods

I am wondering about the post method use into the Thread class.

My program is about to find fixed salary from the basic salary.Basically in this program ,I have one editText where user have to enter the basic salary and when the click on the button called 'show' there is one counter which display on the screen 1,2,3,...10 in textview.Then after the fixed salary will displayed on other editText.So,this about my program

Now,In code I have make one class called Mythread for the counter purpose.In which I have put the loop which count 1,2,...10.But my problem is that the i want to refresh the values of the textView so i want to use post method but how to use in my code that i don't know.

Kindly guide me

```
package com.example.bs_to_fs_thread;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyThread extends Thread{

TextView _tv;
String fs;

public MyThread(TextView tv,String sfs){

    _tv=tv;
    fs=sfs;

}


public void run()
{
    int i=0;    
    while(i<10)
    {

    _tv.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {

                _tv.setText(i);
                i++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        }
    });
    MainActivity.printFS(fs);


}
```

}

`
In this code ,may be I write the _tv.post(Runnable{ });
on wrong place pls give me the view of this post method and how should and where should i write this post method? and why?

Comment: Your fault is at run() method. You can't use "any" user interface operation at that method. You must use runOnUiThread() method for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this(I have not tested it dont have editor now):

```
public MyThread(TextView tv,String sfs,Activity a){
this._tv=tv;
this.fs=sfs;
this.a= a;//this is required to use method runOnUiThread as background thread cannot modify Ui thread
}
```

Then in the place where you want to modify your UI like change text do something like this:

```
a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            Toast.makeText(a, "show some toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            _tv.setText("mytext");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void run() {
    int i = 0;    
    while(i < 10) {

        // We can't use 'i' directly inside the runnable declaration, because all
        // external variables must be declared as final
        final int number = i;

        // Posting this runnable to the UI thread
        _tv.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                _tv.setText(number);
            }
        }

        // Sleeping current thread (NOT UI thread) for 1 second
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Increment 'i'
        i++;
    }
    MainActivity.printFS(fs);
}
```